# GridView OnClick Not Working

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I have implemented RecyclerView, and for each recyclerView item i have GridView and it's corresponding adapter.

When i am trying to listen to the recyclerView onClick() item, it listening to the click event for whole area except the area or space taken by the gridView.

```
public ChildViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(hallNameAdapter != null){
                Adapter adapter = (Adapter) hallName.getTag();
                if(showMovieTimeAdapter != null){
                    adapter.onHallClick();
                }
            }
        }
```

Child View Holder Xml.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.movie.bms.utils.customcomponents.TextViewRoboto
        android:id="@+id/show_time_fragment_cinema_hall_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20.9dp"
        app:textStyle="roboto_medium"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="#555555"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/show_time_fragment_images_lin_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="11.3dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/show_time_fragment_cinema_hall_name"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/show_time_fragment_reserve_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20.9dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/show_time_fragment_m_ticket_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20.9dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <com.movie.bms.utils.customcomponents.CustomGridView
        android:id="@+id/show_movie_timings_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/show_time_fragment_images_lin_layout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20.9dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13.3dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="4"
        >
    </com.movie.bms.utils.customcomponents.CustomGridView>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/show_time_fragment_separator"
        android:layout_below="@id/show_movie_timings_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#79d6d6d6"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated on this.

Comment: Please post some relevant block of code.

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick) link here it is solved

Comment: This piece of code is part of my RecyclerViewHolder class, which implements the View.OnClickListener().

Answer (score -1):

`RecyclerView` doesnt have a `onItemClickListener` like listview or gridview

u Have to set a `onCLickListener` in the `viewHolder` of your `recyclerview` adapter

Comment: `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` also doesn't have `onClickListener`

Comment: i said you have to set it inside viewHolder not on ViewHolder

Comment: Thanks for pointing out.  But i have implemented the listener on viewHolder only in the recycler View Adapter. I thought it's obvious so i didn't mention it in my question.

Comment: why do u think so it is so obvious

Comment: please post your childholder xml layout code , could be a xml issue

Comment: it's not xml issue, but stilli i have posted, have a look.

Comment: i cant find it anywhere

Comment: What happend, @ankitagrawal. Not able to find the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104163/discussion-between-ankitagrawal-and-ritesh).

Comment: Let's not do that for now.